# Error on R at trying to get median from values in a text file

Tags: r

I created with python a simple text file with 100 real numbers between 0 and 10 (one value per line).

So I read and set it in a variable 'a' on R, with 'read.table()' function

The mean() function works fine, but the median() function returns the following error when used 'a' as parameter (my R:Base is PT_BR version, so I'm translating the error messages to English. I don't know it is equal to the original English version)

```
#Error in median.default(a) : need numeric data
```

So i tried to convert it to numeric

```
as.numeric(a)
#Error: object (a) cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

So I tried to convert to a list and get the median

```
a <- as.list(a)
median(a)
#Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
#'x' must be atomic
```

Printing the list:

```
a
$V1
[1] 0.003 0.161 0.227 0.331 0.416 0.441 0.536 0.619 0.730 0.737 0.764 0.799
[13] 0.939 1.009 1.036 1.217 1.321 1.615 1.684 1.878 1.930 1.933 1.949 2.018
[25] 2.053 2.126 2.181 2.464 2.488 2.725 2.838 2.874 2.893 2.954 3.054 3.092
[37] 3.149 3.192 3.216 3.233 3.422 3.424 3.695 3.720 3.743 4.097 4.229 4.229
[49] 4.264 4.317 4.447 4.461 4.529 4.794 4.992 5.121 5.138 5.161 5.241 5.264
[61] 5.286 5.428 5.430 5.430 5.498 5.520 5.706 5.928 5.956 6.074 6.154 6.398
[73] 6.402 6.536 6.549 6.748 6.994 7.196 7.397 7.440 7.840 7.854 7.862 7.913
[85] 7.976 8.002 8.151 8.185 8.237 8.485 8.632 8.688 8.718 9.200 9.372 9.401
[97] 9.487 9.615 9.701 9.702
```

What is this $V1?

How i get the median?

Comment: try `median(a$V1)` or `median(a[[1]])` or `median(unlist(a))` or `median(scan("data.txt"))`

Comment: All solutions worked o.O

Why?

Comment: by the way, your edit of my edit succeeded mostly in uglifying the results ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have read the data in as a data frame: that means that the basic structure is a list of columns.  Even though there's only one column in this data frame, you need to extract it before you can apply a numeric operation like computing the median.  As you will see at `?"[["`, there are a variety of ways of indexing a data frame.

```
median(a$V1)
median(a[[1]])
```

both pull out the first column.

```
median(unlist(a))
```

drops the list structure.

```
median(scan("data.txt"))
```

uses `scan()` instead, which reads the results in as a single vector rather than as a list of vectors (i.e. a data frame).